# How to print a Image.png in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, png, printdocument

Currently i am developing a desktop app, and i need to print a image (png file) from a local storage (desktop).

It's simple, when i push a buttom, it would be send the image to print. Look my function, it does not work.
(for proofs i printed a image in PDF printer, but when i open the pdf of the image, the PDF is empty).
I added from the toolbox a PrintDocument1.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Certificate

    Private streamToPrint As StreamReader
    Private ReadOnly pd As New PrintDocument()

    Private Sub PrintCertificateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintCertificateButton.Click

        Try
            streamToPrint = New StreamReader("C:\Users\m.cerna\Desktop\screenshot.png")
            Try
                pd.Print()

            Finally
                streamToPrint.Close()
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred trying to print" & vbCrLf & "Error code: ", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You probably want to load an Image object and subscribe to the `PrintDocument.PrintPage` event. You should avoid hard-coded paths like that. The file won't be there when you deploy.

Comment: How? i dont undestand, i am new in this lenguage, sorry :(

Comment: Well, if *How?* is related to loading an Image, the you can change `Private streamToPrint As StreamReader` to `Private certificateImage as Image` and write `certificateImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([Your Image Path])))`. To add a handler to the PrintPage event, follow the example in the Docs: [PrintDocument.PrintPage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage), which I understand you have already seen, but implemented partially. In the event handler, draw your Bitmap using the `PrintPageEventArgs` Graphics object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!
i changed my function, i used:

AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintImage

i share my new function :) i found it at: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/25494.aspx

```
Private Sub PrintCertificateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintCertificateButton.Click

    Try
        AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintImage
        PrintDocument1.Print() 
    Catch ex As Exception 
        MsgBox(ex, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error during Print")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub PrintImage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ppea As PrintPageEventArgs)
    ppea.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:\Users\m.cerna\Desktop\screenshot.png"), ppea.Graphics.VisibleClipBounds)
    ppea.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This creates a new `PrintPage` handler each time you click the `PrintCertificateButton`. Don't do that. Move this line `AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintImage` to the Form's constructor or the `Load` event. AND remove it in the Form's close/closing event: `RemoveHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintImage`.